# What are the practical disadvantages of using strongly typed data interchange format (eg thrift / capn proto) in a microservices context?

Tags: json, serialization, thrift, microservices, data-interchange

I'm thinking of introducing a strongly typed (read - with predefined schema) data interchange format for communication between our internal services. For example, I guess something like Thrift or Cap'n Proto.

At least two obvious advantages (to me) of using this over something like JSON is that

1. you would KNOW the exact format of the data the service can expect (so leaves less room for ambiguity and errors while communicating) and
2. the implementation generally deserializes the raw message for you and it provides methods for accessing the objects.

What are the practical disadvantages for going this route, versus something like JSON?

For context - our system consists of services written in python and java - and possibly other languages in the future, and communicates via HTTP endpoints between services and message brokers like rabbitmq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with every strongly typed system, one of the major advantanges is without a doubt that if you make mistakes, it **fails early** in the process, typically at the compilation stage, which is a good thing.

Second biggest advantage IMHO is what you already said: because the fields and types are well known, the compiler, libraries and related code know what data to expect and thus can be written/organized in a more efficient manner - or in short: **performance**.

In contrast, a losely typed system (like Avro), while allowing for much greater **flexibility** without the need of recompiling, comes with the other side of the same coin: the downside of being prone to errors regarding the contents of the message at runtime.

This is because a losely defined system defines only the syntax of a valid document (like for example XML) and leaves the message-level semantics of what's in the document up to the upper layers. A strongly typed system has the knowledge about those message-level semantics already built in **at compile time**. Therefore, it is easy to detect/decide whether a particular document or message is not only well-formed but valid with regard to the message contents. If you need to do the same with the losely defined system, you need to provide additional information **at runtime** (like XML schema) and validate your document against it.

### Bottom line

What system you prefer is more or less a matter of taste in most cases. I'd make the decision based on the question, how variable the data are that I have to deal with. If it makes sense to use a strongly typed system, I'd go that way, because I like it very much to get informed about errors and mistakes early.

However, if there is a need for very flexible data structures, it may make more sense to go the other road. Although designing a losely typed schema on top of a strongly typed system is surely possible, it is somewhat contradicting and you'll end up with some overly complicated, while overly generic, thing.

Comment: w.r.t. XML; it's quite interesting using the XER encoding rules for ASN.1. The serialisation output is then XML, and it's unavoidably well formed, valid, etc. Confuses the hell out of people who don't know how it was generated!

Comment: @bazza: You like irrritating and confusing people, obviously?

Comment: It's for their own benefit, ultimately :-)

Comment: Avro supports compile time generated as well.  Did you mean to say "like JSON"?

Answer (score 1):

**Typed**

Incoming messages that are type tagged is very liberating, so long as it's possible to tell what the incoming message is without reading all of it. If so then you no longer care so much about message order. This is because it's easy for the recipient of the messages to handle whatever it is sent. So you can have an application which just sits there taking whatever it gets, and just does whatever is appropriate for each one.

**Format**

A schema language that allows you to define value and size constraints is very useful. It means that the sender of a message cannot accidentally send an invalid one. Moreover the receiver can automatically tell if an incoming message meets the schema. This is a real bonus in implementing a network service; the vast bulk of the message validation is done for you!

By size constraint, I mean that you can specify how long an array is in the schema and the generated code will refuse to handle arrays longer or shorter. By value constraints, imagine a message field called "bearing"; you might want to constrain that to be between 0 and 359.

These both allow you to make a clear, unambiguous statement about what the interface is and have it enforced automatically. How many security bugs have there been recently where some network interface data validation has been badly implemented...

**Options**

One serialisation standard that does all this is ASN.1. The tools I've used take an ASN.1 schema and produce code to serialise and deserialise, automatically checking that the value and size constraints have been met and also telling you what an incoming message type is. The tools for ASN.1 can be quite elderly and are in need of updating. If updated it would be ideal for every purpose, with both binary and text wire formats available.

There's now JSON schemas too, and they seem to have type, value and size constraints. This might be what you're looking for.

I'm fairly sure that Google Protocol Buffers doesn't do type tagging very well, and doesn't do value and size constraints. I've seen comments in GPB schema along the lines of:

// musn't be greater than 10.

If that's what is being written into a schema, the schema language is arguably inadequate...

I'm not sure of Thrift, I'm not sure it does value constraints (someone correct me if I'm wrong please!).

**Disadvantages**

Can't think of any! It can irritate developers; code they thought was good can be readily revealed to be producing junk messages, which annoys them intensely...